# Does Google Ads show conversion data if the linked GA4 "App and web metrics" setting is off?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, magento

A PPC marketer is saying that since the site I am responsible for updated to GA4 from UA, they are not seeing any conversion data.

The site is Magento 2.4.5, which has a core module to add Google Ads' Conversion ID and Conversion Label.  This module was previously working with UA.

Whilst I found [this Magento bug report](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37736) saying they are having a similar problem, my assumption is that the PPC marketer just does not understand how to configure Google Ads with GA4, and it is not a Magento bug.

My current findings:

- Google Analytics seems to be showing conversions, but Google Ads (Goals > Summary) does not.
- A goal action called "Purchase" (which I believe is a default one)
  with a conversion source of "Website"  says "Needs Attention".  There
  is a second goal, also called "Purchase" with a conversion source of
  "Website (Google Analytics (GA4))".  Neither show data,
- I double checked and am confidant that the Conversion ID and Conversion Label I put into Magento match what Google Ads are looking for.
- When I looked at the Linked Accounts in Google Ads, the GA4 one has the setting "App and web metrics" set to off.
- A UA linked account also appears here, but I assume that's a legacy
  thing and not related to this issue.

My current assumption is that the GA4 "App and web metrics" just needs turning on, that conversions are collected by GA4 and passed to Google Ads, and Google Ads can only access that data if you give it this permission.

I only have read-only access to the Google Ads account so can't test it, but does that a sound likely theory?  If not, anywhere I should be looking?

(I have no prior experience with Google Ads, so feel free to correct any incorrect assumptions I am making above)

edit: I also noticed that Magento loads to Gtag.js with the id parameter 1234567, but the non-GA4 action asks for it to be loaded as AW-1234567.  Magento automatically strips the AW- bit, but I was wondering if you need to tell Adwords that you don't require that, perhaps under Tools-Google Tag (which I can't access)?

edit 2: I see there are "purchase" events and "conversion" events to log a site purchase.  The latter seems a pre-GA4 way of doing things. Am I right in assuming this?

Comment: Running a troubleshooter shows that it can see the tag GT-1234567 but not AW-1234567. I now assume my first edit is going to be the solution, and Magento simply doesn't handle the legacy AW prefix tags.